# Basic android Web Service not working

Tags: android, web-services

I'm just trying to do a simple web service with my android sample project and can't seem to get it working. 
Here is my code:

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private final String URL = "http://blah/Service1.asmx";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";
private String TAG = "SOAP";
private static String message;

Button b;
TextView tv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

     b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //Button Click Listener
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    getMessage();

            }
        });
    }

public void getMessage() {

    //Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    //Property which holds input parameters
    PropertyInfo messagePI = new PropertyInfo();
    //Set Name
    messagePI.setName("Practice");
    //Set Value
    messagePI.setValue(messagePI);
    //Set dataType
    messagePI.setType(String.class);
    //Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(messagePI);
    //Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    //Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    //Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        //Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        //Get the response
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;


        if(result !=null){
            tv.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
        }


        //tv.setText("" + results);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        tv.setText(e.getMessage());
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I step through it it errors out at the line `SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);` saying that it's from an `AndroidRuntime Error`... I've literally just copied this code from a tutorial so it should work but can't seem to figure out why not.

LogCat:

```
07-08 07:07:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(6979): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
07-08 07:07:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(6979):     at com.example.mysoap.MainActivity.getMessage(MainActivity.java:100)
07-08 07:07:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(6979):     at com.example.mysoap.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:58)
07-08 07:07:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(6979):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2482)
07-08 07:07:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(6979):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9077)
07-08 07:07:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(6979):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-08 07:07:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(6979):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 07:07:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(6979):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-08 07:07:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(6979):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-08 07:07:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(6979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 07:07:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(6979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-08 07:07:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(6979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-08 07:07:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(6979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-08 07:07:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(6979):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is a screenshot of my libraries that I have.

[image]

Here is my logcat of the second problem now...

```
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429): java.lang.StackOverflowError
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.String._getChars(String.java:1040)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:155)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:215)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219) 
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at   org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo.toString(PropertyInfo.java:219)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:203)
07-08 09:38:10.515: E/AndroidRuntime(7429):     at org.ksoap2.serializatio
```

This is what line it errors out on now `androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);`

Comment: clean and rebuild... it looks like it is setup correctly, but sometimes Eclipse just gets it wrong.

Comment: It still doesn't work even after a clean and re-build... :(

Comment: Actually just looked at the `logcat` again and it now says `java.lang.StackOverflowError` rather than `NoClassDefError`

Comment: You probably want to paste the new logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ksoap jar file to your libs directory in your project so that when the apk is built the jar will be bundled into it. The exception you are getting tells me that the code was not bundled correctly so you get a class not found error.

Comment: I think I have already taken care of that and it still wasn't working, I added what my libs looks like in the edit, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, but I can't see the whole name is it: ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies the with dependencies library?

Comment: Yes it's called `ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar` I don't think it's added to the android dependencies? I'm not really sure though